# Создать gzip архив своими руками

Tags: zip, deflate

Потребовалось получить gzip архив. К сожалению gzip.exe делает какие-то не такие архивы, поэтому пробую создавать архивы своими руками. Разобрался, что нужно взять шапку {31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xB} + deflate(text).str(2, -6) + crc(text) + text.size. То, что нужно удалить первые два и последние 4 байта из результата deflate() понял методом тыка. Зачем это делать не понятно совершенно. Особенно не понятно, как восстановить эти байты, чтобы засунуть в inflate() и расшифровать. Подскажите, как это делается. И, главное, для чего.

Comment: Зачем нужно делать gzip-архив руками?
`gzip file_name.file` должен заархивировать всё как надо
`gzip -d archive.gz` должен разархивировать всё как надо.

Comment: Нет, gzip не подходит. Тут непонятная программа, которая хочет странный gzip, жму руками с нулевым сжатием. gzip жать в 0 не умеет, минимум -1. То есть программа с виду новая, но почему она не понимает стандартный gzip, хоть убей, не понятно. Хотя сама жать умеет. Подозреваю, что у нее какой-нибудь старый gzip, несовместимый с новыми.

Comment: @mikelsv, так Вам нужен не стандартный, а точно не известно какой формат архива?

Попробуйте покопаться в старых rfc. Хотя, тут возможна ведь ситуация, что для этой программы вообще нужно что-то свое.

Кстати, а архив созданный ей (если она их умеет делать) стандартный gzip.exe понимает?

Comment: @avp это определенно gzip. gzip.exe понимает архивы программы. Так же понимает мои архивы, по вышеописанному алгоритму, со сжатием 0-2, ставлю сжатие выше, gzip ругается при распаковке: unexpected end of file. Программа понимает только мои архивы с нулевым сжатием. Мой gzip 1.3.12, deflate() из zlib-1.2.8. Попробую что ли собрать gzip 1.6, может хоть мой формат начнет понимать. А то прям цирк.

Comment: Поправка. deflate() упорно и молча съедал часть буфера при сжатии 3 и выше. При низком, ругался на нехватку памяти и получал сколько надо. А формат gzip реально получается тот, который я описал. Создается чувство, что они там обкурились. Если хватит упорства разберусь, как оно распаковывается и как восстанавливаются выкинутые байты.